# VBA Class Module Cannot Be Accessed Nor Exported - Error "Invalid Data Format"

Tags: excel, vba

I think the title of question says it all.

Are these modules lost to me, or is it possible to recover?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK when opening file I select Open and Repair

When given the options between repair and extract, only extract works - I am then able to access corrupted modules

[image]